# ng-template [NgForOf] return undefined value

Tags: angular, undefined, primeng, primeng-datatable, ng-template

I have the next problem: construction

```
<p-dataTable [value]="listOfAddresses" [expandableRows]="true" [expandedRows]="listOfAddresses" ">
    <p-column>
        <ng-template let-item="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
                {{i+1}}
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column >
         <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="listOfOriginalAddresses" pTemplate="body">
             {{item.Street + " " + item.City}}   
         </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-table>
```

Returns undefined values for item.Street and item.City
 Strange because if I use

```
<p-column >
   <ng-template pTemplate="body">
      <div *ngFor="let item of listOfOriginalAddresses">
          {{item.Street + " " + item.City}}   
     </div>
   </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

I have all required values but all the list in the row. What  is the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved but not with using of ngFor.

I create pipe:

```
 transform(value: any): any {
        let item = value;
        return (item.Street + " " + item.Country);
    }
```

Furthermore, data don't change according to the edition in the fields with parced address, what solved another headacke.

Answer (score 0):

Do use [Elvis operator][1], by having ? it will check if object defined

```
{{item?.Street + " " + item?.City}}
```

Comment: result the same. Object in the row but values looks like 'undefined undefined'

Comment: @Antatrix  try this let item of listOfOriginalAddresses|async

Comment: used in second variant <div *ngFor="let item of listOfOriginalAddresses | async as items"> get error "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: can you show us the  console.log of listOfOriginalAddresses ?

Comment: make sure you have this statement inside your service code .map(res=>res.json());

Comment: have you tried to put second *ngFor inside the ng-template pTemplate="body" ?

Comment: @LucaTaccagni yes, but result the same.